# Public and private API keys

Tags: api, hash, hmac, api-key

I'm developing an API system which requires this type of authentication. The user will send an HTTP request with its id, the data, and a hash (the data hashed with the private key) and then in the server I check if the hash matches with the same procees here.
Is it like the implementation must be?
And I'm going to use as public key the id of the client but what is the best method to generate the private key, sha256 of the id, of a randon number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checking out what [amazon s3](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#ConstructingTheAuthenticationHeader) is doing for the authentication might be a good start

basically they are doing the same thing as you proposed, and they use RFC 2104HMAC-SHA1 for the hashing. The implementation depends on your choice of languages.

Comment: Which is the best method for you to generate the prvate key? Thanks

Comment: @Mario check out this for generating random stuff https://www.grc.com/passwords.htm

Comment: I have a doubt: if I generate the private key with random stuff I'll have to send it to the client (an Android app) so a sniffer willbe able to discover the key. What about generate it from the email or other stuff on both sides? Is it better?

Comment: @Mario if you're concerned about man-in-the-middle attack, you should use https, or just send the key by email

Answer (score 2):

This is not Private/Public-key cryptography. In such a system, the client would encrypt **the whole data** and you would then decrypt it using your private key. You would never give your private key to the client.

What you are doing is request signature. You give a "secret" (what you are calling "private key"), then they use this to generate a hash. You can then check the hash on your server since you also know the secret.

There would not be a public key in this kind of system. You normally identify the client using a session key or token, so the client needs to authenticate first (which means you need some authentication method). Essentially, what you are trying to implement is OAuth. Perhaps have a look at the library and see if you can use it directly - http://oauth.net/documentation/getting-started/